# close console input c++

Tags: c++, input, cin

I'm reading integers in "while" on console, how to stop reading when I type an empty string?

```
while (cin >> index)
{
    if (index >= v.size() || index < 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    n_v.push_back(v[index]);


}
```

[I want it to break when an empty string is read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfXpy.png)

I would be greatful, if someone helped me.

Comment: @user0042 Not really, since "empty" input is a newline, and newline is a whitespace, and (non-character) input operations by default skip leading whitespace, so it will block.

Comment: read a string instead of an int and check it is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve your problem: The first is simply that the user enters the end-of-file key combination (typically <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> in Windows, and <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> on Linux or macOS).

The other is to read the input line by line as strings, and check if the line (stripped of all spaces) is empty. If not then attempt to convert the string to a number and continue with the code.